# Python checking its own code before running (Usage Errors)

Tags: python

I would like to build something into my Python module that can throw a warning if the user has not done something correctly. For example if the user has a while loop with nothing in it that will block threads, or a user does not initialize something correctly.

Currently I am loading the python file before it runs with a "pre-runtime" script to check these warnings. However it still requires the user to run this pre-check script. I would like to figure out how to do this in my main module. Aside from loading the python script as a string and then parsing it I can't think of a good way to do this.

For example if the user runs this code

```py
import myModule
test = myModule.module()

print("Hello")

while 1:
    True
```

They would get

```py
>> Warning, you used a print statement, they have no power here.
```

Or the alternative example in the other direction

```py
import myModule
test = myModule.module()
```

They would get

```py
>> Warning there is no while True loop, your code will just exit
```

Comment: Most IDEs will check this automatically for you...

Comment: Yes they will check normally errors that are pythonic. I am looking for special case handling related to this specific application. As a super basic example let's say I never want a user to use "print("hello")", again silly example but exactly the kind of case I am looking at. Python will not catch this as an error but in the context of my system it is an error.

Comment: So you're trying to look for usage errors?

Comment: if you are sure you are going to input a valid python code, something from https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html can help

Comment: Yes exactly. So the user would import this module in main.py. the user would then use some print statements in there module. Then when the program is run the module would produce some warnings saying it doesn't like print statements.

Comment: I should elaborate a little more. I am trying to catch if some code does exist ie print statements and if some code doesn't exist. So if the user forgets to use something that they are supposed to. Assuming that these things cannot be handled in the general context of the module.

Comment: this is doable with what I linked, although I am not sure how easy / difficult that is, using `ast` you can tell if there are `print` calls in a python file, so that should apply to any callable or any valid python statement / expression

Comment: BTW, edit your question elaborating exactly what you want, instead of in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just writing this as a solution because I found this interesting, there may be better ways to accomplish.

**check.py**

```
import ast

with open('temp.py') as file:
    module_node = ast.parse(file.read())

for node in ast.walk(module_node):
    # check if there is `while True` loop
    if isinstance(node, ast.While) and isinstance(node.test, ast.Constant) and node.test.value is True:
        print('There is a `while True` in the code', node.lineno)

    # check if there is `print` call in the code
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Call) and node.func.id == 'print':
        print('There is a `print` call in the code', node.lineno)
```

**temp.py**

```
import foo # check.py does not run this import

while 1 > 2:
    while True:
        print('some text', '12321')
```

Output

```
There is a `while True` in the code 4
There is a `print` call in the code 5
```

So you get the idea, you just add in conditions in the for loop and have a message printed. Again, there may be better alternatives.

Comment: Very cool, this is exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks for pointing out ast, it is a very cool module. Then I can probably direct `os.path.basename(__file__)` to open the script automatically so the user doesn't have to import it. Solution found! Thanks!

Comment: glad to know this was helpful, can you mark this as accepted then @Meozaa?